# Upload file with Selenium when more than 1 Input with same class detected

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So I have page structured like this :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="buttonUpload" custom="call.js">Button Upload</span>
                <input class="fa-cloud-upload" name="file" type="file" accept="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="buttonUpload" custom="call.js">Button Upload</span>
                <input class="fa-cloud-upload" name="file" type="file" accept="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="buttonUpload" custom="call.js">Button Upload</span>
                <input class="fa-cloud-upload" name="file" type="file" accept="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to upload file only to the first input tag using `send_keys()` from selenium but for some reason it's not working, if there's only single li tags shown after refresh then the codes work, my code as bellow :

```py
view_videos = WebDriverWait(driver, self.latency).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[i18n='i18n.openLink']")))

for i in range(len(view_videos)):
    # some other script here

    uploadme = "/home/user/myfile.png"

    #script to upload
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class='fa-cloud-upload']").send_keys(str(uploadme))
```

I even try with driver wait and select all element with selected array:

```py
#script to upload
upload_first = WebDriverWait(driver, self.latency).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='fa-cloud-upload']")))
         
upload_first[0].send_keys(str(uploadme))
```

But nothing happened, I execute also javascript to erase 2 `<li>` tags after the first one before upload but still upload not working, nothing happens, I just want to upload to first input only using selenium, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `By.CLASS_NAME, 'fa-cloud-upload'` or `EC.presense_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'its xpath'))`
You can find Xpath of the element in F12 panel. Inspect the element, then right click on it in F12 panel and copy -> Xpath.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion by using presence of element and use xpath (I tried xpath in chrome dev tool and it located the input element I want) when driver wait I get the correct class (I print the class to prove) but upload not happened, any other clue?

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the first `<input>` tag instead of `presence_of_all_elements_located()` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul > li input.fa-cloud-upload"))).send_keys(str(uploadme))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul/li//input[@class='fa-cloud-upload']"))).send_keys(str(uploadme))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I can detect the input using presence of element but send keys not working (I can confirm it by print the class), using element to be clickable I always got selenium time out exception any other way?

Comment: After checking, there are JS script that called after i press "Button Upload" to show upload window, is this have any effect?

Comment: @RikudoPain Can you just copy, paste, execute the code and let me know the ststus please?

Comment: copy paste using css selector return error     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: copy paste using xpath result in the same     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: